# Triggering a input file click does not bring the file upload dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, unity-game-engine

I have the following HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/link" style="position:absolute; left:-1000px;">

    <input type="file" name="gameUpload" id="gameUpload" /> 

</form>
```

I am trying to integrate the upload feature in HTML into unity.

The idea is when a button is clicked in unity engine, it will make a call to a javascript function and the js function will trigger the click on the file input element.

This works perfectly fine in Firefox and IE10, IE9 and IE8. But it is not working in Chrome and Safari.

The JS code:

```
function uploadImage(){

jQuery("#gameUpload").trigger("click"); 

}
```

I tried having a "span" with some text and tried triggering the file input's click when that text is clicked, that worked fine.

Also, I did the following to check whether the click is triggered:

```
 jQuery("#gameUpload").unbind("click").bind("click",function(){
    alert("I am open");
 });
```

Apparently, the click is getting triggered because I am getting the alert but the file dialog is not getting opened.

Comment: no can do, that's a security nightmare...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with HTML in Unity, but I don't think you need the JS.

Just including the `<input type="file" name="gameUpload" id="gameUpload" />`  should allow the browser to open a dialog window.

Comment: The <input type="file" name="gameUpload" id="gameUpload" /> will not be visible to the user that is why I am trying to trigger it through a js code.

Comment: you can't fake the *real* user click needed to open a file dialog for security reasons, but in chrome you can use a label to click on a hidden input[type=file].

Comment: Yes I tried triggering a click through a label and it worked, that is why I went for this approach. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, just do this:

```
$('#imageUpload').click();
// or get the HTMLElement
$('#imageUpload').get(0).click();
```

Use html only (as we know, label with for attribute will focus the form element's default actions so.)

```
<label for="imageUpload">Upload File!</label>
<input id="imageUpload" type="file" style="display:none"/>
```