# File upload is not triggering on confirm using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and it does not work in Chrome if I keep the trigger function inside the confirm function but it works in Firefox and Edge.

```js
fileInput = $('<input type="file" id="upload-file" name="timing-upload" style="display:none;"/>');

if (confirm("Are you sure you want to replace all files?")) {
  $(fileInput).trigger('click');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But it works if we remove the confirm condition in Chrome.

```js
fileInput = $('<input type="file" id="upload-file" name="timing-upload" style="display:none;"/>');
$(fileInput).trigger('click');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

There is already a similar question [Triggering a input file click does not bring the file upload dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17688621/3835843) but not any satisfied answer.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have errors in your console?

Comment: Can you post the code in the confirm() function? It seems your confirm function is returning false...

Comment: @LajosArpad There is no error in the console.

Comment: @BrunoFenzl Confirm func returns true as I have logged a console and it shows in the console window.

Comment: How do you know that the second code work? Because in your sample codes there is no clue for your claim.

Comment: @pouyan   It works in FF and Edge but not in Chrome. Sorry I didn't update the code here.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra, Surprisingly both of your code snippets are working on FF. So again there is no clue for your claim!

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra, in chrome none of your code snipts work. while in FF both of them are working. So I'm still confused about your problem.

Comment: @pouyan The confirm works in Chrome but not trigger.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra, I understand that. But in chrome, in your second code snippet, the Trigger doesn't work too.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint inside the block where you intend to trigger the click, will it ever jump there?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but according to the [**confirm documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm#Notes) I think that this is the reason that the code doesn't work in chrome:

> Starting with Chrome 46.0 this method is blocked inside an [**`<iframe>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) unless it sandbox attribute has the value allow-modal.